# IPHONE: How do I override the "cancel\call popup-box" that comes when dialling a number programmatically?

Tags: iphone, phone-call, openurl

I'm currently developing a project that at some part calls a number of the user's choosing. I use the snippet below to call the number.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newNumberString]];
```

The problem is that the box that pops up has buttons with titles in English, but my program is not in English, so it kinda sucks :(

Is there a way to override the title on the cancel\call buttons or maybe an alternative way of dialing a number from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my application the title/buttons are correctly localized by the system. You should try to set your iPhone to the language you want to use.